# Problems with LDIFDE Skipping Users while importing?

Tags: windows, command-line, active-directory

I am attempting to use LDIFDE to export users, groups, and OUs for importing into a different domain.  I'm at the stage where I'm importing users, and I've noticed a problem.

I utilized this command to export users from my domain controller:

```
ldifde -f Exportuser.ldf -p subtree -r "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=User)(givenname=*))" -l "cn,givenName,objectclass,samAccountName"
```

This is the bare minimum required, because if you run the command without the -l filters, you end up with data that wont import, and stops the import.

Anyways, I get users out perfectly fine with the script (that is, it runs), and they even import with the -i -f Exportuser.ldf command no problem.  However, while importing the group membership associations I got some errors that gave me cause to look closer at what I'd created.  To wit:  The command above skipped quite a few users in the process of export.  These range from system accounts to actual active users, though the "hardest" hit was an OU where we keep deactivated accounts.  Not a single strange flag goes up, either.

I can't seem to find anything special about these various users that they'd have in common, but I'm still looking.  In the mean time, I thought I'd check to see if anyone here had any history of LDIFDE simply just blowing past users.

Thanks,

M.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

The filter (givenname=*) does not handle null values.  The givenname attribute refers to the First and Last Name fields for the User account (not the display name).  Therefore, if those fields have no value, (givenname=*) will filter those users out.

M.